# 'dropdownlistfor' controller not taking the selected value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I am facing an issue with dropdownlistfor controller for MVC3 razor engine, that it is not rendering with the selected value.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmploymentStatusID, Model.EmploymentStatusList, string.Empty)
```

Using model am passing the data and everythng is fine till the data get to dropdownlistfor. I attached the image of cshtm page here which I got while debugging. But when rendering the selected option is not coming. What is going wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DropDownListFor` does not use the `Selected` property of the `SelectList`.  It uses the value of property (EmploymentStatusID in your case).  In other words, it uses the value from the model, not from the `SelectList`.

I'm not sure why you're using a `MultiSelectList` anyways, a `DropDownList` can only have a single selected value.

Comment: Oh Thank you Erik, since I am new to MVC, i am not able to understand what happened there. Now i am able to clear the issue with your clue. Thanks again.